# Looking for an idiomatic expression meaning “empty vessels make the most noise”

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

> “An empty vessel makes the loudest sound, so they that have the least wit are the greatest babblers.” — Plato

Ich kann es nirgendwo finden. Gibt es ein entsprechendes Idiom auf Deutsch?

Comment: Gerade Redensarten existieren sehr oft nur in einer einzigen Sprache. »It's raining cats and dogs« gibt's nur auf englisch, und »da steppt der Bär« wird's nicht in vielen anderen Sprachen als deutsch geben.

Comment: Im Deutschen kann es immerhin "junge Hunde regnen" ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Deswegen fragt er ja auch nach einem "entsprechenden Idiom". Und ich finde in diversen Sprichwort-Indizes *Es regnet Hunde und Katzen*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spontaneously I can think of the following proverbs/expressions:

> Viel Lärm und nichts dahinter.
>   Leere Wagen klappern am meisten.
>   Leere Töpfe klappern am Lautesten/machen den meisten Lärm.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprichw%C3%B6rter) nennt zudem:

> "Ein leerer Topf am meisten klappert, ein leerer Kopf am meisten plappert." Beyer 587

Comment: _"Die lautesten Kühe geben die wenigste Milch."_ passt auch gut in die Reihe.

Comment: Da das Töpfe-Ding Platon manchmal zugeschrieben wird, mitunter sogar als "Dose", im unsäglichen Lügennetz der "Zitate" ohne konkrete Quellenangaben, könnte man neben der übersetzenden Antwort auch noch ergänzen, dass in den deutschsprachigen Übersetzungen der Schriften Platons keine Entsprechung zu finden ist, weil das halt nur eine Pseudoautorenangabe darstellt.

Answer (score 1):

Eine Ergänzung.

Die Zuschreibung eines solchen Bonmots ohne konkrete Quellenangabe im Netz zu irgendeiner Person ist üblicherweise ganz einfach glatt gelogen, erfunden oder als Witz gemeint. In [diesem](https://www.newsweek.com/what-does-empty-barrel-mean-and-where-does-it-come-689864) [Fall](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=empty%20barrel) [ist](https://yourstory.com/2017/03/29-quotes-by-plato/) es allerdings nicht selten, das Sprichwort Plato anzudichten. Das sieht beeindruckend aus, und ist völlig ohne Grundlage in den Werken Platos. Also eigentlich ein Simulacrum des Sprichwortinhalts.

Bessere Seiten bringen zu "Leere Dosen machen den meisten Lärm" die korrektere Angabe "(ohne Autor)", andere erfinden Shakespeare als Autor, geben "[deutsches](http://www.fritzsche-bellersheim.de/aphoris2.html) [Sprichwort](https://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/51535)" als Ursprung an. Treffender wäre es natürlich nur im klingonischen Original auszudrücken.

Da in der Frage noch immer steht

> > […] Plato
>
> Ich kann es nirgendwo finden. Gibt es ein entsprechendes Idiom auf Deutsch?

Es ist bei Platon nicht zu finden.

Eine Stelle im [Kratylos](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kratylos) ist jedoch halbwegs ähnlich:

> *Cratylus:* In my view, Socrates, he is not articulating them as he should.
>
> *Socrates:* Well, that's a welcome answer. But are the words he articulates true or false, or partly true and partly false? If you tell me that. I'll be satisfied.
>
> *Cratylus:* For my part. I'd say he's just making noise and acting point-
> lessly, as if he were banging a brass pot.
> <sub>Übersetzung nach John M. Cooper: "PLATO COMPLETE WORKS", Hackett Publishing: Indianapolis, Cambridge, 1997. ([Archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/platocompleteworkscollection/(Plato)%20Plato_Complete_Works_djvu.txt))</sub>

Eine deutsche Variante dazu lautet dann:

> *Kratylos:* Ich glaube, o Sokrates, er würde das ganz umsonst gesprochen haben.
>
> *Sokrates:* Ich muß auch damit zufrieden sein. Denn würde er Wahres oder Falsches sprechen? Oder zum Teil etwas Wahres, zum Teil Falsches? Denn auch das würde genügen.
>
> *Kratylos:* Ich möchte sagen, er mache nur ein Geräusch und setze seine Zunge wirkungslos in Bewegung, so gut als wenn er auf einem ehernen Kessel trommelte.
> <sub>Platon: Sämtliche Werke. Band 1, Berlin [1940], S. 541-617.
> Entstanden zwischen 393 und 388 v. Chr. Erstdruck (in lateinischer Übersetzung durch Marsilio Ficino) in: Opera, Florenz o. J. (ca. 1482/84). Erstdruck des griechischen Originals in: Hapanta ta tu Platônos, herausgegeben von M. Musoros, Venedig 1513. Erste deutsche Übersetzung durch J. G. Zierlein in: Magazin der deutschen Kritik, herausgegeben von C. von Schirach, Band 1/2, Halle 1772. Der Text folgt der Übersetzung von Julius Deuschle von 1855. ([zeno.org](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Platon/Kratylos))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I have immediately had to think of "Stille Wasser sind tief". It's not the same, but it looks almost like an inverse formulation of the same fact: It's not those who talk the most who are the "best". It's calm and silent people who often surprise you with unexpected wisdom, capabilities,..

Answer (score -2):

> Hunde die bellen beißen nicht.

dürfte das bekannteste Sprichwort sein, dass die Bedeutung wiedergibt.

Comment: M. E. wird die Bedeutung nicht wiedergegeben. Im Originalzitat geht es darum, dass jemand viel redet, obwohl er keine Ahnung hat. Bei Deinem Zitat sehe ich es so, dass jemand Drohungen ausspricht, diese aber nie wahrmacht. Siehe auch https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hunde,_die_bellen,_bei%C3%9Fen_nicht

Comment: Schließe mich Raketenolli vollumfänglich an.

Comment: Ich dachte auch an "Große Klappe, aber nichts dahinter." Damit sind jedenfalls keine leeren Drohungen gemeint, sondern ein allgemeines Maulheldentum, das den Beweis seiner hochtönenden Versprechungen schuldig bleibt. In einem banalisierenden Sinn trifft das auch auf den Bellende-Hunde-Spruch zu: Die bellen halt nur, und je lauter, desto weniger muss man sie ernst nehmen. Allerdings geht's bei leeren Töpfen eher um Hohlköpfigkeit und dummdreistes Herumprollen, um in der Analogie zu bleiben, weniger um Angst-Gekläffe.